# I have a Code like this and I want to shorten it

Tags: python

number
output the square of the difference of the numbers.
For example, if the given number is 352, then it is the maximum number made from the digits of this number
532 and the minimum number is 235. The square of their difference is (532-235)(532-235) =297*297 = 88209.

The code is working but I need this code abbreviation :)

```
l1 = []
l2 = []
number = int(input("Enter a 3-Digit Natural Number:"))
if 99<number<1000:
    one = number % 10
    two = number // 10 % 10 
    three = number // 100 % 10
    l1.extend([one,two,three])
    l2.extend([one,two,three])
    l1.sort()
    l2.sort(reverse=True)
    Big = l1[0]*100 + l1[1]*10 + l1[2]
    Small = l2[0]*100 + l2[1]*10 + l2[2]
    Answer = (Big-Small)**2
    print(Answer)
else:
    print("Restart the program")
```

Comment: What is the variable `eded`? Also *why* do you need the code abbreviated? It isn't particularly long as it is. Is this some sort of homework stipulation that you need to satisfy?

Comment: for one: you don't need to convert the input to `int`. Leave it as a string so you can manipulate characters, and that way you don't need place values. You also don't need two separate lists, just use `sorted()` on one list. And you can sort the numbers while they are strings, and then use `"".join()` to turn the list of strings back into a single string, and then `int()` at the end to turn it into an int

Comment: but the string manipulation is much easier than math with place values

Answer (score 3):

Don't write code which expects three digits. Write code which expects any number of digits. Your code will be more reusable and it will be simpler:

```
digits = str(number)
ordered = sorted(digits)
small = int(''.join(ordered))
big = int(''.join(ordered[::-1]))
```

Comment: since `number` is the value returned by `input()`, there is no reason to convert it to a string: just don't convert it to `int` in the first place.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Right, let me fix it.

Comment: @Esther Sure, but then there should be a different way to check that it is an integer of correct length.

Answer (score 0):

I abbreviated your code as follows:

```
n = input("Enter a 3-digit natural number: ")
if 99 < int(n) <= 999:
    min = list(n)
    min.sort()
    max = list(n)
    max.sort(reverse=True)
    print((int("".join(max))-int("".join(min)))**2)
else: print("Something went wrong!")
```